# How to copy/paste from lstlistings?

Tags: listings, verbatim, copy-paste

I'm trying to write code in a LaTeX document that can be copy/pasted from an outputted pdf using Adobe Reader and that also word wraps, rather than breach the right margin.

I've found that in verbatim mode I can copy/paste, but there isn't an option to enable word wrapping. In lstlistings I can enable word wrapping, but can't figure out how to make the text copy/paste properly. I get extra spaces when trying to copy/paste from Adobe Reader X. From searching online, it seems like I just need to choose what's inside lstset{...} correctly, but can't figure it out.

See the following example and the results after copy/pasting from the compiled document (notice the additional spacing)

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm,tmargin=1.5cm,bmargin=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}  % Environment meant for source code (useful for word-wrapping verbatim text)
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,breaklines=true} % Word wrap within listings environment

\begin{document}
\lstset{basicstyle = \verbatim@font}

\begin{lstlisting}
//Define Variables
Test1_up = [XZ:This (Index)][1];
Test2_down = [XZ:This Index][1];

//Specify Parameter Values
beta1 = .2238202445016966;
beta2 = .6676275732948469;
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{verbatim}
//Define Variables
Test1_up = [XZ:This (Index)][1];
Test2_down = [XZ:This Index][1];

//Specify Parameter Values
beta1 = .2238202445016966;
beta2 = .6676275732948469;
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

And the output after copy/pasting:

```
// Define Variables
Test 1_ up = [XZ: This ( Index ) ][1];
Test 2_ down = [XZ: This Index ][1];
// Specify Parameter Values
beta 1 = .2238202445016966;
beta 2 = .6676275732948469;
//Define Variables
Test1_up = [XZ:This (Index)][1];
Test2_down = [XZ:This Index][1];
//Specify Parameter Values
beta1 = .2238202445016966;
beta2 = .6676275732948469;
```

Answer (score 20):

The problem with spaces in the pasted text is in the fact that `listings` adds spaces between letters, unless the option `columns=fullflexible` is used.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm,tmargin=1.5cm,bmargin=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}  % Environment meant for source code (useful for word-wrapping verbatim text)
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,breaklines=true} % Word wrap within listings environment

\begin{document}
\lstset{basicstyle = \ttfamily,columns=fullflexible}

\begin{lstlisting}
//Define Variables
Test1_up = [XZ:This (Index)][1];
Test2_down = [XZ:This Index][1];

//Specify Parameter Values
beta1 = .2238202445016966;
beta2 = .6676275732948469;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's what I get from copy-pasting:

```
//Define Variables
Test1_up = [XZ:This (Index)][1];
Test2_down = [XZ:This Index][1];
//Specify Parameter Values
beta1 = .2238202445016966;
beta2 = .6676275732948469;
```

Note that `basicstyle=\verbatim@font` will throw an error.

Comment: Thanks @egreg - that works. (Though I didn't get an error from basicstyle=\verbatim@font)

Comment: @user32268 Yes, @-commands are allowed in `\lstset` (which I don't agree with, by the way).

Comment: `columns=fullflexible` eliminates the spaces from the listing completely, not just removes the "extra" artificaial spaces from the rendered output. That corrupts the listing's formatting.

Comment: @ajeh If you use a proportional font, yes. If you use a monospaced font, no.

Comment: How can I use monospaced font with listings?

Comment: @ajeh It's in the answer: `\lstset{basicstyle = \ttfamily,columns=fullflexible}`

Comment: ttffamily is just too ugly :(

Comment: @ajeh There are several monospaced font available.

Comment: doesn’t work for me, unfortunately, the spaces are still there

Comment: For me, the spaces are gone when copying the text in Adobe Acrobat Reader, but present in Sumatra PDF.

Comment: With `columns=fullflexible` the spaces disappeared. I tested it in `evince`.

Comment: @Daniel It's viewer dependent.

Comment: This almost works for me (Evince on Ubuntu), but the spaces at the start of each line are lost; so indentation disappears.

Comment: @user4417 As I said, it's very viewer dependent, but yes, generally initial spaces are lost.

Comment: Is there a viewer which will not remove the initial spaces?

Comment: @user4417 Sorry, I don't know. I myself rarely use `listings`.