# How to copy/paste multiple spaces from lstlistings?

Tags: listings, verbatim, texniccenter, copy-paste

This is a continuation of a question that I asked already: [How to copy/paste from lstlistings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119218/how-to-copy-paste-from-lstlistings).

The solution presented there does not work if the text within the lstlistings environment contains consecutive spaces. Consecutive spaces get copied as a single space. See the following example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm,tmargin=1.5cm,bmargin=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}  % Environment meant for source code (useful for word-wrapping verbatim text)
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,breaklines=true} % Word wrap within listings environment

\begin{document}
\lstset{basicstyle = \verbatim@font}

\begin{lstlisting}
There are no spaces in here []
There is one spaces in here [ ]
There are two spaces in here [  ]
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The the contents get copied/pasted such that the third line only contains one space, when it should contain two. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
There are no spaces in here []
There is one spaces in here [ ]
There are two spaces in here [ ]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, space characters cannot reliably be copied from a PDF. [This answer on Superuser](https://superuser.com/a/61701) is bang on:

> The problem with PDF is that it doesn't really encode text. All it
>   does is pretty much saying "Put those glyphs there, and those glyphs
>   there". It's a format intended for print and high-fidelity document
>   preview on screen but not so much to actually retain any semantics or
>   contents.
>
> So the only thing a PDF reader can see is what letters are
>   approximately on a line. It can't see spaces as a space character,
>   since there is no such thing in a PDF. All it has is smaller and
>   larger gaps between letters. And thanks to kerning or justified text
>   those aren't even consistent.
>
> So what PDF readers usually do is to guess what gaps are spaces and
>   what gaps are not. Depending on the algorithm used the results are
>   fairly good or horrible.

Besides, here are three other reasons why you should think twice before encouraging your readers to copy & paste code typeset in a PDF (e.g. with `listings`).

1. copying listings that span multiple pages of a PDF document is tedious and error-prone;
2. the results of copying content from a PDF for subsequent pasting vary widely from one PDF viewer to another (and you don't have control over which viewer(s) your readers use);
3. line breaks introduced by `listings`'s `breaklines`, if copied and pasted "verbatim", may translate to invalid syntax in the language used.

It simply is not a reliable way of distributing code.

Comment: There *is* however a way to tell PDF readers what text to copy. I once saw a PDF which displayed one text and, when copied, copied a totally different text. So, how can we use this with LaTeχ, copying precisely the listing?

Comment: @mirabilos I don't know whether that's possible.

Comment: @mirabilos, @jubobs: [This question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18483/) mention `accsupp`, which seems to provide this functionality.

Comment: @MartinJ.H. `accsup` doesn't completely solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Many pdf readers will have acceptable results when copy and pasting from \lstlisting environment. Maybe this will help:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  literate={\ }{{\copyablespace}}1 {\ \ }{{\copyablespaceTwo}}1
}

\usepackage[space=true]{accsupp}
\newcommand{\copyablespace}{\BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=00A0}\ \EndAccSupp{}}
\newcommand{\copyablespaceTwo}{\BeginAccSupp{method=hex, unicode, ActualText=00A000A0}\ \ \EndAccSupp{}}

\begin{document} 

\begin{lstlisting}
There are no spaces in here []
There is one spaces in here [ ]
There are two spaces in here [  ]
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```