# how to wrap a long terminal command without real line breaking?

Tags: listings, verbatim

this may look like a duplicate question to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116534/lstlisting-line-wrapping) and many, but really I had a hardtime in finding the desired solution.

The 
`breaklines=true` didn't work as it breaks the long command. Hence simple `copy and paste` doesn't work, because  when the code is pasted in terminal it gets split over many lines with  preceding angle brackets > .

Comment: Your main question here is about the fact that the visual output should have a line-break in it, but when you copy-and-paste it should not?

Comment: This is a copy/paste problem, probably the solution is to use `accsup`

Comment: ...and a copy-and-paste problem fixed by [`accsupp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/accsupp) might be reader-dependent.

Comment: @Werner, Yeah that's what I want.

Comment: @Werner, any copy-and-paste will be reader-dependent. For example even a plain `listings` usage will give different copy behavior. In my Evince the copied code includes random spaces (I need to use `accsup` to make it behave the same in Acrobat and Evince, even if I don't mind the line breaks).

Comment: Just don't. Copying and pasting from PDF is too unreliable; listings, in particular. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195489/how-to-copy-paste-multiple-spaces-from-lstlistings/195495#195495

Answer (score 2):

Use `accsupp` package. This way you can copy regarless of visual line breaks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\BeginAccSupp{method=plain,ActualText=long long long command long long long command long long long command long long long command}
\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines=true]
long long long command long long long command long long long command long long long command
\end{lstlisting}
\EndAccSupp{}
\end{document}
```

If the code includes special characters you need something more fancy (`method=pdfstringdef` and `hyperref`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\BeginAccSupp{method=pdfstringdef,ActualText=
grep -rw --include \unichar{"005C}*.h --include \unichar{"005C}*e.c* "Write()" . |sed -e 's/Write/Read/g'}
\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines=true]
grep -rw --include \*.h --include \*e.c* "Write()" . |sed -e 's/Write/Read/g'
\end{lstlisting}
\EndAccSupp{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not working for my case as I have a command like `grep -rw --include \*.h --include \*e.c* "Write()" . |sed -e 's/Write/Read/g'` which is not a plain text.

Comment: That is why you have to show a MWE to have better answers later. The problem in your case is the "\" character. There are workarounds within `accsup` for this problem, see my edit.