# LaTeX symbol for single quote mark that MATLAB will recognize

Tags: symbols, matlab, csquotes

I'm writing MATLAB code in LaTeX and I would like to be able to cut and paste it directly into the MATLAB command window. One critical symbol is the `'` (single quote). When processed by LaTeX it shows up as a curly quote sign, which MATLAB doesn't recognize. I've looked through the "Comprehensive Symbol Table", but I couldn't find anything. The csquotes package looks as though it *might* be helpful, but I found the manual incomprehensible.

Comment: Use a verbatim-like command or environment (package `listings` or `matlab-prettifier` (which is based on `listings`) are my recommendations).

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195489/how-to-copy-paste-multiple-spaces-from-lstlistings/195495#195495

Answer (score 2):

Discovered the answer, related to Paul Gessler's comment.    There's a wonderful style file called mcode.sty that uses the listings package but seems to deal with  some of it's shortcomings.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8015-m-code-latex-package

Comment: You should have a look at the [`matlab-prettifier`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/matlab-prettifier) package; it improves upon `mcode` in many ways. See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891), for instance.

Comment: Thanks very much, I made the switch!    Took a bit of work to set it up, but seem to have succeeded.     I may learn other advantages as I got, but the main reason I converted was being able to place inline matlab commands with double quotes, e.g., in matlab, "sym" means...  That facility is worth a lot to me!     Is there an easy option to add color to all inline statements, i.e., anything separated by "'s?    Also, while Beta Mono is *much* nicer than the default, it would be nice if I could use a *non* monospaced font just for comments, i.e, anything after a % sign.   Is that possible?

Comment: *Is there an easy option to add color to all inline statements, i.e., anything separated by "'s?* What you mean is unclear, but know that you can alter the style of inline code when defining `"` as a shorthand with `\lstMakeShortInline"`. Try, for instance, `\lstMakeShortInline[basicstyle=\color{red}]"`. *[...] it would be nice if I could use a non monospaced font just for comments, i.e, anything after a % sign.* Simply pass the desired style to the `mlcommentstyle` key, e.g. `mlcommentstyle = \rmfamily\color[RGB]{034,139,034}`.

Comment: matlab-prettifier has been working nicely